Jenkins pipeline step that conditionally requires user confirmation
I'm trying to create a Jenkinsfile with three stages: A, B C, where stage A has these properties:

if the git branch is develop then A always runs
for any other git branch a prompt is displayed: "Run A ?"

if the user says 'yes' then A is run (followed by B and C)
if the user says 'no' then A is not run, but B and C are still run




You can do this via when condition.
I did something like this a little while ago.
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('A') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    branch 'develop'
                    expression {
                        def userInput = input(message: "Run A?", ok: 'Proceed', parameters: [choice(name: 'RunStageA', choices: ['Yes', 'No'], description: 'Select Yes to run stage A')])
                        return env.BRANCH_NAME != 'develop' && userInput == 'Yes'
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Running stage A'
            }
        }
        stage('B') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running stage B'
            }
        }
        stage('C') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running stage C'
            }
}
}
}


Try this one
